# Как запросить повышение привелегий?

Tags: c#

Как запросить повышения прав пользователя. Например если это инсталятор службы, то функция установки даёт ошибку - не хватает прав. Многие инсталяторы делают это обычным диалогом при запуске. Т.е. окно на весь экран с двумя полями: логин и пароль. Думаю каждый кто работает из-под пользователя знает это окно. Если работа идет из-под администратора (не корневого) то в окне две кнопки - да и нет. Как такое сделать на с#?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3600322/check-if-the-current-user-is-administrator Там можно чекнуть текущие права. Так можно залогиниться https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905407/how-to-use-windows-authentication-in-windows-application

Comment: Хорошо, допустим логин пароль мы ввели, а дальше...? Обязательно ли перезапускать процесс, или можно учетку сменить текущему процессу?

Comment: Вверху взять логин пароль и применить его так  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net/26872651 И майкрософт кажись почитывает SO https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsimpersonationcontext

Comment: @nick_n_a если нужен стандартный UAC prompt - то обязательно перезапускать. Идея показывать кастомный диалог, косить под UAC и спрашивать у пользователя имя и пароль - так себе.

Comment: @PashaPash т.е. правильно делать, это "shell-ом" запускать себя с "пунктом меню" "Run as administrator", и будет ок? Я как раз пришел к выводу, что не могу понять почему в случае админской учётки Да/Нет спрашивает UAC, и как Да эмулировать... наверно никак.

Comment: @nick_n_a UAC запрещает некоторые действия даже администратору, если процесс не был запущен с повышением привилегий - запись в Program Files, например, или некоторые действия с реестром. Полноценно эмулировать - никак, в этом как раз и есть идея UAC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Возможны варианты

1. Вариант с перезапуском, проверить

   ```
    static internal bool IsRunAsAdmin()
        {
            WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal principal = new WindowsPrincipal(id);
            return principal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);
        }
   ```

и перезагрузить программу выполнив

```
 ProcessStartInfo proc = new ProcessStartInfo(); 
    proc.UseShellExecute = true; 
    proc.WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory; 
    proc.FileName = Application.ExecutablePath; 
    proc.Verb = "runas"; 
    try 
    { 
        Process.Start(proc); 
        Application.Exit(); // Завершить текущую.
    } 
    catch 
    { 

    }
```

2. Вариант с ресурсами (будет всегда запрашивать)

Ресурс  RT_MANIFEST долен сожержать

```
<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2"> 
   <security> 
      <requestedPrivileges> 
         <requestedExecutionLevel 
            level="requireAdministrator" 
         /> 
      </requestedPrivileges> 
   </security> 
</trustInfo>
```

Через студию можно так (цитата): Чтобы настроить уровень повышения привилегий в данном проекте Visual C# Windows Forms, откройте свойства проекта, перейдите на вкладку «Безопасность», поставьте флажок напротив пункта «Включить параметры безопасности ClickOnce-приложений», выберите «Это приложение с полным доверием», а затем закройте страницу Свойства приложения. Это приведет к созданию файла app.manifest и настроит проект для встраивания манифеста. Вы можете открыть файл "app.manifest" в обозревателе решений, развернув папку Свойства. В файле содержится следующее содержимое по умолчанию. Строку

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false" />
```

Заменить `asInvoker` на `requireAdministrator`

3. (Ошибочный) Если есть учётка (логин пароль) или её токен, то можно применить учетку.

   ```
    WindowsIdentity newId = new WindowsIdentity(_tokenHandle);
    WindowsImpersonationContext ctx= newId.Impersonate();
    ....
    ctx.Undo(); // отменить действие учётки
   ```

А далее возможны варианты. Получить токен можно так
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35426713/5727271 (тут не хватает Undo).

Админская учётка может не иметь полных прав, даже если извесны логин и пароль. Полные права можно получить через UAC (1 и 2).

Думаю если программа будет странным способом клянчить учётку - не вариант. Возможно вариант подойдет, если где-то шифровано её хранить.

---

P.S. Проанализировал как это делают FAR и Total - там принцип тот же что в [1], но чуть усложнили. Когда происходит security-error - запускается вторая копия приложения (с повышением привелегий, при этом появляется диалог). Потом с второй копией программы устанавливается связь, и прилегивированую операцию делает вторая копия, а первая используется как "консоль".

Ссылки

- http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/CSUACSelfElevation-644673d3
- http://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/impersonating-and-reverting