# Как запустить код VSC от имени администратора?

Tags: visual-studio-code

как можно запустить код в Visual Studio Code от имени администратора? Видел такое:

> Добавьте в проект файл App.manifest (ПКМ по проекту - добавить -
>   существующий элемент) и в блоке  
>   раскомментируйте следующую строчку:
>
> < requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator"
>   uiAccess="false" / >,

не понимаю как это сделать?(возможно отстал в развитии)

Comment: где взять этот манифест?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как запросить повышение привелегий?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010719/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b9)

Answer (score 0):

Можно запустить VSCode от админа и вроде как будет вам админ