# C# запуск с UAC

Tags: c#, .net, процесс, uac

Подскажите как запустить процесс через `Process.Start();` с визулизацией UAC

Comment: Вы хотели сказать запуск от имени администратора?

Comment: @aepot нет Именно дожно быть включено UAC

Comment: Оно и так всегда включено, конкретизируйте вопрос.

Comment: Вот так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010719/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b2%d1%8b%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%b8%d0%b9/1011009#1011009 Можно выполнить команду runas. Диалог сам появится если он нужен.

Comment: UAC может не отобразится только к примеру если вы запустили программу1 использовав UAC а из программа1 запускаете программа2 как дочерную с наследованием. Например если запустили тотал из под UAC, а из под тотала запускаете утилиту администрирования которая требует UAC. Или если UAC отключен. (Но если он отключен то и привелегилированные ф-ции будут доступны без)

Comment: @aepot его можно отключить, хоть и сложно. Уже не помню как. В винде администратор может быть без полных прав (без UAC) и с UAC. Хоть это и странно... но как-то так.

Comment: @nick_n_a в вопросе это не указано, а когда параметр не указан - используем значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Согласен. Ничего не указано. Не все понимают что такое UAC, сам писал - удивился.